# Writing more than one row of data to each plist

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, plist, overwrite

my cocos2d game high score's are written into a plist. Every time i go into the plist only one row of data is written, every time I write into the plist it overwrites the previous data?

Heres my code for writing to my plist:

```
-(void)writeToPlistHighScore {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,@"HighScore.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [plistDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:scoreNumber] forKey:@"Level2_HighScore"];
    [plistDict writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];
    NSLog(@"HighScore wrote: %i", HighScore);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're creating a new, empty NSDictionary every time. Then you add one score and save that dictionary.

You need to initialize your dictionary with the existing plist so that the dictionary loads the existing highscores:

```
NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: writeToFile:filePath];

// if dictionary is nil the highscore file doesn't exist yet
if (plistDict == nil)
    plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Also, don't forget to release the dictionary when you're done! Right now you're leaking memory.

```
[plistDict release];
```